# "Table 'nest.auth_user' doesn't exist"

Tags: python, django

I am creating a custom user registration form and I keep getting this error. How do I correct this.

```
> ProgrammingError at /Identity/register/ (1146, "Table 'nest.auth_user'
> doesn't exist")
```

I adjusted the authentication system to use email instead of username and I switched from SQlite to Mysql.

```
# Create  models for Identities app.

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.

class UserManager(BaseUserManager): 

    # Create a model manager for User model with no user name field


    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):

        # Create and save a User with the given email and password

        if not email: 

            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):

        # Create and save a regular User with the given email and password.

        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):

        # Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.

        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')

        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractUser):

    # User Model

    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email add '), unique = True)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()
```

I registered the User Model:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as DjangoUserAdmin
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from .models import User

# Add User profile from models document

from Identities.models import UserProfile

# Register your models here.


@admin.register(User)


class UserAdmin(DjangoUserAdmin):

    # Create administration model for custom User model 

    fieldsets = (

        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name')}),
        (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
                                       'groups', 'user_permissions')}),

        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),



    )

    add_fieldsets = ( 

        (None, { 

            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2'),

        }),
    )

    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff')
    search_fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
    ordering = ('email',)
```

I also created a custom user model and registered the model

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    contact = models.IntegerField(default=0)

admin.site.register(UserProfile)
```

I created the register view :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from Identities.forms import CreateAccountForm


def register(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = CreateAccountForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

        else:
            return redirect(reverse('Identities:logout'))

    else:

        form = CreateAccountForm()
        var = {'form' : form}
        return render(request, 'Identities/create_account.html', var)
```

Then I created the class model in forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class CreateAccountForm(UserCreationForm):

    email = forms.EmailField(required = True)


    class Meta:

        model = User

        fields = (

            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2'
        )

        def save(self, commit = True):
            user = super(CreateAccountForm, self).save(commit = False)
            user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
            user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
            user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']

            if commit:

                user.save()

            return user
```

Comment: Why are you using "from django.contrib.auth.models import User" ? if you are making custom user model.

Comment: @NeErAjKuMaR I was following this tutorial : [Custom Django User Registration Form (Django Tutorial)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=66l9b2QrBR8&list=PLw02n0FEB3E3VSHjyYMcFadtQORvl1Ssj&index=16)

Answer (score 0):

You need to migrate first

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
python3 manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to migrate your model files to database...

```
    python manage.py makemigrations
    python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when switching from sqlite to mysql. I guess I'd made auth_user on sqlite and it didn't exist on mysql.
A few things seemed to really help me out.

Restarting Apache: `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

Making a new super user: `python3 manage.py createsuperuser`.

I got this error: `Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.`

So then I did `python3 manage.py makemigrations` and `python3 manage.py migrate` for admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.

Then again: `python3 manage.py createsuperuser`.

It fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also had that error when I referenced my custom `User`-class in a separate Model via a `ForeignKey` for example. I set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in my `settings.py` like this:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "users.User"
```

I fixed it by using that reference from `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` instead. For this, you need to import it first:

```
# Replace this
# from users.models import MyUser
# With this
from django.conf import settings
```

and replace your custom `User`-model with the one from the settings:

```
# Replace this
# owner = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, related_name="budgets", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
# With this
owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="budgets", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```